# Как отсортировать записи по двум столбцам в SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Два дня пытаюсь решить следующую задачу: 
Есть несколько записей в MySQL в формате:

```
Наименование записи | group | order | order1
Запись1             |   1   | 4     |  2
Запись2             |   2   | 3     |  1
Запись3             |   1   | 2     |  5
Запись4             |   1   | 6     |  1
Запись5             |   2   | 6     |  5
```

Как правильно средствами PHP + MySQL сделать выборку записей из группы 1 и отсортировать их одновременно по двум столбцам? 
Т.е. если мы сортируем выборку только по столбцу order, получится список из записей

```
Запись3
Запись1
Запись4
```

Но нужно включить еще сортировку по второму столбцу, т.е. если в order2 в записи из группы 1 стоит единица, то на первое место в списке записей нужно поместить ее.

Если не очень внятно сформулировал вопрос, могу расписать более подробно.

Буду рад и благодарен за внимание и ответы!

Comment: «если в order2» ­— откда взялось order2?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, опечатался, это order1.

Comment: поправьте вопрос. следующее уточнение: «если в order2 в записи из группы 1 стоит единица, то на первое место в списке записей нужно поместить ее» — другие значения из order1 не должны влиять на порядок результирующего запроса? только единица?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не полностью понял вопрос, но как я понял. Имеется 2 поля для сортировки. И если один из полей меньше второго, нужно использовать его при сортировки.

значить если у Вас таблица имеет значения

```
Наименование записи | group | order | order1
Запись1             |   1   | 4     |  2
Запись2             |   2   | 3     |  1
Запись3             |   1   | 2     |  5
Запись4             |   1   | 6     |  1
Запись5             |   2   | 6     |  5
```

и Вы хотите получить результат

```
Наименование записи | group | order | order1
Запись4             |   1   | 6     |  1
Запись1             |   1   | 4     |  2
Запись3             |   1   | 2     |  5
```

тут нужно учесть еще одно вещь, Запись1 и Запись3 имеют одинаковую минимальную сортировку "2", но второе значение "4" и "5", значит если минималное одинаково, нужно сортировать по другому поле.

попробуйте этот код

```
SELECT `Наименование записи`, `group`, `order`, `order1`,
 CASE
        WHEN `order` < `order1` THEN `order`
        ELSE `order1`
    END AS minn,
`order` + `order1` as summ
FROM таблица 
WHERE group = 1 
ORDER BY minn, summ
```

Как это работает, он выбирает минимальное из `order` и `order1`, и сортирует по этому поле. Если имеется несколько одинаковых минимальных, то сортирует по сумме `order` и `order1` так как один из значений равно, и получится сортировка по второму значению.

Comment: Выразил вопрос все-таки довольно сумбурно, но Вы меня поняли верно! Спасибо огромное за ответ, то что нужно!