# Помогите придумать SQL запрос, пожалуйста

Tags: sql, база-данных, select

Только формулировку, с реализацией я надеюсь справлюсь. С этим CASE никогда не работал, поэтому плохо представляю какого типа запрос можно придумать.

Формулировка задания: SQL-запрос SELECT с использованием процедурных возможностей SQL (команда CASE).

Запрос по базе данных компании, которая якобы занимается разработкой ПО.
Логическая модель БД:
[image: Логическая модель БД]

Comment: Бла-бла-бла мы не делаем домашние задания бла-бла-бла его вам дают не для того, чтобы кто-то его сделал за вас /уходит ворчать/

Comment: Если бы я просил сделать домашку - я бы попросил написать реализацию. А тут всего лишь прошу помочь с формулировкой.

Comment: А разница какая? Сформулировать - уже сделать дело.

Comment: Большая) Это не делание домашки, лишь небольшой толчок в нужную сторону.
Мозг иногда способен только с толкача завестись)

Comment: А что за вопрос та? Тут только я не вижу постановки задачи?

Comment: @saidolim-djuraev, нужен _любой_ запрос SELECT с использованием CASE по этой базе данных, а реализацию постараюсь сам сделать.

Comment: попробуйте анализировать этот запрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427376/182317

Comment: @saidolim-djuraev, спасибо большое)
Хотя такой запрос довольно сложный для моих мозгов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, выборка отчётов по проектам с расшифровкой кодов ошибок через `CASE`:

```
select 
t1.[Название проекта], 
t2.[название отчёта], 
case t2.[статус ошибки]
   when 0 then 'ок'
   when 1 then 'предупреждение'
   when 2 then 'срочно'
   when 3 then 'очень срочно'
   else 'неизвестно'
end as 'тип ошибки'
from [Проекты] as t1
inner join [Отчёты об ошибках] as t2 on t1.[ID проекта]=t2.[ID проекта]
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Так гораздо лучше)
И вовсе не обязательно было код писать, за него отдельное спасибо.